# How did Light get the TV in the potato chip bag?

Tags: death-note

In the Death Note anime, there is a [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrpdFmb0EMc) early on in which Light secretly watches a tiny TV hidden in a bag of potato chips.  The thing I don't understand, is that the TV is already in the bag when he opens it.  How did that happen?  Is that just a plothole?

Comment: You can buy a heat-sealer on amazon for a fiver. More's the point, why didn't he notice that the crisp-bag weighs fifty times more than normal?